# Two functions called in v-on:click. Wait for rendering to finish before launching the other?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this div:

```
<div 
  class="item parent-track"
  v-on:click="expandTrack(jsonObject.tracks.indexOf(track));setGrey();"
></div>
```

The method `expandTrack` creates dynamically new items inside the div and I want to launch the method `setGrey` (which applies to all the template) **after the end of rendering.**

It seems that this is not what's happening. The `expandTrack` method launches but `setGrey` is not applying to the items which have been created.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick

Comment: thanks, thanksd :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Vue.nextTick()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) when you need to wait for the DOM to finish rendering before executing code. This method is available on every Vue instance via `vm.$nextTick`.

In your case, it might look like this:

```
<div class="item parent-track" v-on:click="foo">
```

```javascript
methods: {
  foo() {
    this.expandTrack(this.jsonObject.tracks.indexOf(this.track));
    this.$nextTick(this.setGrey);
  }
}
```

---

Or, if you really want all that code in your template, you could do this:

```
<div 
  class="item parent-track"
  v-on:click="expandTrack(jsonObject.tracks.indexOf(track)); $nextTick(setGrey);"
></div>
```